# How to get the path of file when make a jar file in Java

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, jar

I am building a game in java and everything works just fine when I run it in intellij idea with no error .

The problem start when i build my project as jar file.

I have this method :

```
public void addImageOfObject(String add, String dir, ArrayList<ImageIcon> linkedList, Dimension size) {
    Image image;
    String dirc;
    File file = null;
    try {
        file = new File(classLoader.getResource(dir).getFile());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(StaticVariables.mainClass, e.getStackTrace());
    }
    try {
        for (int i = 0; file.listFiles().length > i; i++) {
            try {
                dirc = dir + i + ".png";
                image = loadImage(dirc);
                linkedList.add(new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(size.width, size.height, 4)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(StaticVariables.mainClass, e.getStackTrace());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(StaticVariables.mainClass, e.getStackTrace());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(StaticVariables.mainClass, "file not found ");
    }
}
```

This is the class loader :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
```

I can't get the right path of the file ..when i run it in jar file its give an error file not found on :

```
file = new File(classLoader.getResource(dir).getFile());
```

I call to method with this line :

```
imageLoader.addImageOfObject("src/main/java/","ImageHandel/Photos/character/male/attack/down/",aMale,new Dimension(500,400));
```

This is the path of files

[image]

The number of files I want to get `file.listFiles()`

[image]

In the male folder there is 44 files .. that's the number I want to get in order to run on the loop 44 time and i just can't find the right way to do it! I tried a lot of thing but nothing help me ..

Have any idea what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can create folder on location where your running jar file,

ImageHandel/Photos/character/male/attack/down/

Run it in jar file by considering that location.

use to add static folder for serving images e.g In spring boot we can configure static folder as follows:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/ImageHandel/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:ImageHandel/")
            .setCachePeriod(0);
}
```

Comment: the qeustion is how to get the file path from inside of the jar file

Comment: url/ImageHandel/Photos/character/male/attack/down/xyz.png